# css hide lower div background

Tags: css, html, air

Is it possible to hide lower div background fully?

I have two fixed position divs with shadow - semi transparent background so they overlap and become darker.

Is there a way - in Adobe Air - to make the lower div's background fully hidden?

Comment: What do u mean? Always fully hidden? Or hidden on an action?

Comment: should this also be tagged with adobe air?

Comment: Added adobe-air tag since it is referenced in the question.  Not sure the question makes sense but since I don't know Adobe Air at all I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi Guys, the div below is longer in length like a body background. The above div is header background and both interlace at the top. However, the body background is shadow repeat-y whereas header bg is transparent at the top and hence the body bg is showing from beneath that. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps or what you mean by "in adobe air" but can you not position the background of the second div to start further down with css eg

```
.div2 {
background-position: 0 50%;
}
```

Or you can move it down a set number of pixels maybe.

read more about bg positioning: [w3c schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the seconde div why not use jquery to hide it?

$("div1.class").hide()

Comment: Hi Guys, the div below is longer in length like a body background. The above div is header background and both interlace at the top. However, the body background is shadow repeat-y whereas header bg is transparent at the top and hence the body bg is showing from beneath that. Hope this helps.